# Error: Overload Resolution Ambiguity in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, compiler-errors, bigdecimal

I have this function.

```
fun BigDecimal.percent(percentage: Float) = this.multiply(percentage.toBigDecimal()).divide(BigDecimal(100))
```

Calling the function :

```
somelist.size?.toBigDecimal()?.percent(numString.toFloat())
```

value of numString is "50" or "75"

On calling this function I'm getting compile error :

```
error: overload resolution ambiguity:
public inline fun Int.toBigDecimal(): BigDecimal defined in kotlin
public inline fun Int.toBigDecimal(): BigDecimal defined in kotlin
somelist.size?.toInt()?.toBigDecimal()?.percent(

error: overload resolution ambiguity:
public inline fun Float.toBigDecimal(): BigDecimal defined in kotlin
public inline fun Float.toBigDecimal(): BigDecimal defined in kotlin
fun BigDecimal.percent(percentage: Float) = this.multiply(percentage.toBigDecimal()).divide(BigDecimal(100))
```

I'm not able to figure out what is the problem here. Any solutions or suggesstions please.

Comment: Can you show your imports from the file that is calling the function?

Comment: What type is `somelist.size`?